# Behavior of `subtract` in Higher Order Functions of Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write this function which applies the function `f` twice on x

```
Prelude> applyTwice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
Prelude> let applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

Now, when I try to evaluate the below expression

```
Prelude> applyTwice (`subtract` 3) 10
Output: 10

Prelude> applyTwice (3 `subtract`) 10
Output: 4
```

As per my understanding, `subtract` is a infix function, so the given parameter should fill the empty position (left or right operand) and hence the first expression `` applyTwice (`subtract` 3) 10 `` should behave like

```
10 `subtract` 3 `subtract` 3
```

So, the result in this case should be `4`, but the output is `10`

While in the other case, i.e. `` applyTwice (3 `subtract`) 10 ``, the output is `4`, where I am expecting it to be `10`

Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:subtract

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding of `applyTwice` and of the operator section notation are correct. However, you're probably confused by what `subtract` does. See [the library documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:subtract) which says:

> the same as `flip (-)`

So `subtract` is like `(-)` but with the arguments flipped. Therefore,

```
  applyTwice (`subtract` 3) 10
=
  (`subtract` 3) ((`subtract` 3) 10)
=
  (`subtract` 3) (10 `subtract` 3)
=
  ((10 `subtract` 3) `subtract` 3)
=
  (3 - 10) `subtract` 3
=
  (-7) `subtract` 3
=
  3 - (-7)
=
  10
```

And similarly for the other expression.

Comment: Aaan!! I was subtracting the right operand from the left operand, which is exactly opposite. Thanks for explaining :)